# OSX Safari transitionEnd not fired when tab hidden

Tags: macos, css, safari

I have two tabs open in OSX Safari in the same window. I have a custom CSS3 transition on the first tab and I have subscribed for its onTransitionEnd event. It works fine in normal case, but when I reload the page and switch immediately on the second tab (it doesn't matter what is on the second tab), the onTransitionEnd event not fired on the first tab.

To reproduce the issue:

1. Open this jsFiddle in a Safari tab: http://jsfiddle.net/qzweoL6r/4/
2. Wait for the alert, it should tell you that the transition "ended"
3. Open an another tab for example http://stackoverflow.com
4. Navigate back to the first tab(jsfiddle) and hit the RUN and immediately switch to the second tab
5. Wait for 4 seconds, in normal case the alert should pop-up, but nothing
6. Switch back to first tab(jsfiddle) and if you do not see the alert in #4, now you should see it, but nothing again, just the div's width changed to the 400px transition value.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('div').one('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
      alert('ended');
    })
    .addClass('active');
}, 2000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
div.active {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Do you have any idea how could I fix this browser issue with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem in Chrome as well, and it has been logged as a [bug for Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=852952). React JS and Bootstrap have developed JS workarounds involving timeouts which I think is what needs to be done in the meantime until the browsers fix this issue.

Here is an example of a transitionend workaround for this problem:
https://github.com/Khan/react-components/blob/master/js/timeout-transition-group.jsx